# How to make concurrent API calls using different ID' s on the same page in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an issue. I'm building a component in Angular that needs to display the last 10 customers for a particular logged-in user. I have already built the API controller to get each customer by ID. Within my service I created an Observable that calls the API and returns information by id.

For each of the 10 customers, I need to call this service and return some data. I have tried calling the service for each ID (10 times!) but this clearly isn't the clean way of performing this request.

This is what I've tried so far but this just looks so wrong and dirty.

**route.service.ts**

```
getCustomerAccessList10(): Observable<any> {
    this.loadToken();
    let httpOptions = { 
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json','Authorization':'Bearer '+ this.authToken }) 
      };
    return this.http.get<any>(this.baseUrl + '/api/CustomerAccessList10', httpOptions);
  }
```

**customer.component.ts**

```
  customeraccesslist: CustomerAccessList[];
  dashboardInfo: DashboardInfo[];
  dashboardInfo1: DashboardInfo1[];
  dashboardInfo2: DashboardInfo2[];
  dashboardInfo3: DashboardInfo3[];
  dashboardInfo4: DashboardInfo4[];
  dashboardInfo5: DashboardInfo5[];
  dashboardInfo6: DashboardInfo6[];
  dashboardInfo7: DashboardInfo7[];
  dashboardInfo8: DashboardInfo8[];
  dashboardInfo9: DashboardInfo9[];

  id:number;

  // customer0;
  // customer1;
  // customer2;
  // customer3;
  // customer4;
  // customer5;
  // customer6;
  // customer4

  previousCustomer0;
  previousCustomer1;
  previousCustomer2;
  previousCustomer3;
  previousCustomer4;
  previousCustomer5;
  previousCustomer6;
  previousCustomer7;
  previousCustomer8;
  previousCustomer9;

ngOnInit() {
    this.routeService.getCustomerAccessList10().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.customeraccesslist = res;

    //array containing each ID
        let customerIdArray = this.customeraccesslist.map((x) => x.customerId);

        //map through array and get customerId from each object
        console.log(customerIdArray.splice(0,1));
        
        //assign each customerId in customerIdArray to a variable
        let previousCustomer0 = customerIdArray[0];
        let previousCustomer1 = customerIdArray[1];
        let previousCustomer2 = customerIdArray[2];
        let previousCustomer3 = customerIdArray[3];
        let previousCustomer4 = customerIdArray[4];
        let previousCustomer5 = customerIdArray[5];
        let previousCustomer6 = customerIdArray[6];
        let previousCustomer7 = customerIdArray[7];
        let previousCustomer8 = customerIdArray[8];
        let previousCustomer9 = customerIdArray[9];

        // this.routeService.getCustomerCareDashboardInfoById(previousCustomer0).subscribe(
        //   res0 => {
        //     this.dashboardInfo = [].concat(res0);
        //   }
        // )

        // this.routeService.getCustomerCareDashboardInfoById(previousCustomer1).subscribe(
        //   res0 => {
        //     this.dashboardInfo1 = [].concat(res0);
        //   }
        // )

        // this.routeService.getCustomerCareDashboardInfoById(previousCustomer2).subscribe(
        //   res0 => {
        //     this.dashboardInfo2 = [].concat(res0);
        //   }
        // )

        // this.routeService.getCustomerCareDashboardInfoById(previousCustomer3).subscribe(
        //   res0 => {
        //     this.dashboardInfo3 = [].concat(res0);
        //   }
        // )

        // this.routeService.getCustomerCareDashboardInfoById(previousCustomer4).subscribe(
        //   res0 => {
        //     this.dashboardInfo4 = [].concat(res0);
        //   }
        // )

        // this.routeService.getCustomerCareDashboardInfoById(previousCustomer5).subscribe(
        //   res0 => {
        //     this.dashboardInfo5 = [].concat(res0);
        //   }
        // )

        // this.routeService.getCustomerCareDashboardInfoById(previousCustomer6).subscribe(
        //   res0 => {
        //     this.dashboardInfo6 = [].concat(res0);
        //   }
        // )

        // this.routeService.getCustomerCareDashboardInfoById(previousCustomer7).subscribe(
        //   res0 => {
        //     this.dashboardInfo7 = [].concat(res0);
        //   }
        // )

        // this.routeService.getCustomerCareDashboardInfoById(previousCustomer8).subscribe(
        //   res0 => {
        //     this.dashboardInfo8 = [].concat(res0);
        //   }
        // )

        // this.routeService.getCustomerCareDashboardInfoById(previousCustomer9).subscribe(
        //   res0 => {
        //     this.dashboardInfo9 = [].concat(res0);
        //   }
        // )

        //console.log(customer0)
        //let customer1 = customerIdArray[1];
        //console.log(customer1)
        //let customer2 = customerIdArray[2];
        //console.log(customer2)
        let customer3 = customerIdArray[3];
        //console.log(customer3)
        let customer4 = customerIdArray[4];
        //console.log(customer4)
        let customer5 = customerIdArray[5];
        //console.log(customer5)
        let customer6 = customerIdArray[6];
        //console.log(customer6)
        let customer7 = customerIdArray[7];
        //console.log(customer7)
        let customer8 = customerIdArray[8];
        //console.log(customer8)
        let customer9 = customerIdArray[9];
        //console.log(customer9)

        // this.id = customer0;

        // this.routeService.getCustomerCareDashboardInfoById(this.id).subscribe(
        //   res => {
        //     console.log(res);

        //     let customerRatingArray = this.dashboardInfo.map((x) => x.customerRating);
        //     customerRatingValueArray
        //   }
        // )
      }
    )

    //get dbo.CustomerCareDashboardInfo by CustomerID for each customer
    this.routeService.getCustomerCareDashboardInfoById(this.id).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
        //customerRatingValueArray
      }
    )

  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

this is very strange, maybe i don't understand but you could do somting like :

```
let previousCustomer: Array<number> // creating an array of customer
customerIdArray.forEach(function (value) { 
  previousCustomer.push(value);  // push the value for each
});
```

and the next step is doing the same with your calls

```
let dashboardInfo: Array<any>
previousCustomer.forEach(function (value){
this.routeService.getCustomerCareDashboardInfoById(value).subscribe(res0 => {
     dashboardInfo.push(concat(res0))
  })
})
```

I don't know if this is something like that that you are looking for.
You will get a, array of data of all your previousCustomers

Answer (score 0):

I'd use forkjoin, hope this helps.
[Forkjoin Learnings](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin)

The one caveat I would warn against is when one sub. fails in forkjoin they all fail, but that can be overcome by handling failures. my go to is
`.pipe(catchError(x => of(null)))`, so when you add the api calls you could push something like `myServiceMethod(id).pipe(catchError(x => of(null)))` and do a null check when you loop through your results

```
 //array containing each ID
let customerIdArray = this.customeraccesslist.map((x) => x.customerId);

const apiCalls = [];
  //map through array and get customerId from each object
console.log(customerIdArray.splice(0,1));
for(const id of customerIdArray) {
  apiCalls.push(myServiceMethod(id));
}
 forkJoin(apiCalls).subscribe((customerResults: any[])) => {
   console.log(customerResults[0]);
   for(const result of customerResults) {
     console.log(result);
   }
 }
```

Comment: you could also probably use a higher order operator with forkjoin inside of it (think mergemap or concatmap, where the inner observable returned is a forkjoin like I show above), but that's too much buzz for the use case IMO